How can I read standard input by lines in a Python one liner?
What is the equivalent of
ls | perl -ne 'print "test $_"'

in python
I just want to pass the result of a unix command to the python interpreter.

Within a Python file you can use the subprocess library and use subprocess.run()

https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir

You can run external commands from within Perl, too, using qx. Do you want to know how to read standard input in Python?

perl expressions are at top of all over PERL still preexist iin ndustry even it's old language. As far as I know there is no such replacement exists for $_ in Python

Don't ask to translate. Ask what doe something do, or ask how to do that thing in the other language.

There is no direct equivalent. The main thing you are making use of is the -n option, which provides an implicit loop around the given code. You are also using a variable that the loop implicitly sets. With Python, you'd have to supply a similar loop explicitly.
One possibility that doesn't require you to embed literal newlines into the Python script (but is otherwise not idiomatic Python) is
... | python -c 'import sys; [print(f"test {x}", end="") for x in sys.stdin]'

Abuse of the list comprehension is to avoid the need to write something like
... | python -c 'import sys
for x in sys.stdin:
  print(f"test {x}", end="")
'

Also unlike Perl (which allows multiple -e options to build up a script piecewise), Python allows only one -c option; everything following that is considered an argument to the -c script itself, not additional arguments for python to process.
